# Undeclare prefix in XML issue for SQL Server

Tags: xml-parsing

I am currently trying to insert an xml node into a table field within SQL server using the below code. I have tried to declare the namespace within the insert but I continue to get undeclared prefix. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
Declare @Term XML = '<wma:Term>My First Term</wma:Term>'
Declare @x XML 
Select @x = MetaData from [Products] where Id = 1
Set @x.modify ('declare namespace wma="http://www.google.com/wma"; insert     sql:variable("@Term") as last into (/wma:WMA/wma:List)[1]
```

Expected results:

```
 <wma:WMA xmlns:wma="http://www.google.com/wma">
      <wma:List>
        <wma:Term>My First Term</wma:Term>
      </wma:List>
    </wma:WMA>
```